# Delete key from state (Redux Reducer)

Tags: javascript, redux

I have a state in Redux that currently renders like this:

**Before click:**

```
{0: {
    open: false,
    negation: false,
    close: false
    },
1: {
    open: false,
    negation: false,
    close: false,
    bool: "and"
    }
}
```

**After click:**

```
{0: {
    open: false,
    negation: false,
    close: false
    },
1: {}
}
```

**I'd like to completely remove the key 1 (in general it's [action.id]).**

Currently the cases in the reducer are:

```
case 'HANDLE_INCREASE_CHANGE':
  return {
    ...state,
    index: state.index + 1,
    [state.index + 1]: {
      open:false,
      negation: false,
      close: false,
      bool: 'and'
    }
  }
case 'HANDLE_DECREASE_CHANGE':
  return {
    ...state,
    index: state.index - 1,
    [state.index]: {}
  }
```

The wrong part is:

```
[state.index]: {}
```

Can you help me please? thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 8):

You should just be able to call `delete state[action.id]`. Although as you're in a reducer function, you should take a copy of the state first, delete from that, then return the copied version.

```
case: 'HANDLE_DECREASE_CHANGE':
  const next = {...state}
  delete next[action.id]
  return next
```

Comment: Its already a copy, so you could just return `next` instead of destructuring to create a third object, but good answer.

Comment: That's true, you don't want to mutate `state`, but you made a copy of it by doing `const next = {...state}`. So all I'm saying is technically you could just do `return next`

Comment: @BrianThompson You're absolutely right. I've updated my answer accordingly. It was a force of habit always writing return {...} in reducers. I actually misread your original comment, which is why I deleted my reply, as it didn't make any sense

Comment: This breaks the `no-case-declarations` ESLint rule.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting new properties to state object, to remove then you need to use `delete`. Remember to make a copy of the current sate first.

```js
case: 'HANDLE_DECREASE_CHANGE':
  let nextState = {...state}
  delete nextState[propToDelete]
  return nextState
```

I believe it would be best to have an array of elements and not set properties directly to the sate object.

```
const iniitalState = {
 index: 0,
 elements: []
}

case 'HANDLE_INCREASE_CHANGE': {
  state.elements.push({
    open:false,
    negation: false,
    close: false,
    bool: 'and'
  })
  return {...state, index: state.index + 1, elements: [...state.elements] }
}
case 'HANDLE_DECREASE_CHANGE': {
  let newElements = [...state.elements]
  newElements.splice(action.indexToRemove, 1) // Removes Element

  return {...state, index: state.index - 1, elements: [...newElements] }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**delete** the key you want removed:

```
const resultingState = {...state, index: state.index - 1}
delete resultingState[state.index]
return resultingState
```

or extract it away with rest parameters:

```
const {...extractedState, [state.index]: ignored} = state
return {...extractedState, index: state.index - 1}
```